# Odoo - how to customize product attributes by date

Tags: odoo-11

I'm trying to figure out if Odoo is suitable for a travel agency
I have a "hotel" article that has some variations:

- by type of room (single, double)
- by season (for example from April 1st to March 23rd)

Can Odoo manage this last variant?

How could I do ?

Answer (score 0):

You could manage seasonal prices using pricelist rules if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: yes, that's what I'm looking for
Can you tell me a guide or where should I go to see?